# iOS 6 opening bogus Apple website when connecting to WiFi

Tags: iphone, wifi, ios

I recently upgraded to iOS 6 on my iPhone 4, and since then I am unable to connect to *any* WiFi. When I try to connect to WiFi, it briefly connects, then brings up a dialog to a bogus Apple website. What is going on?

I don't have a proxy server setup, or anything like that.

So far I have:

- Rebooted access points
- Restarted Phone
- "Reset Network Settings" on my iPhone

Here is what is brought up:

[image]

That just magically appears when I try to connect to WiFi from Settings.

**EDIT**:

Seems like [many other people are being affected by this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19625354#19625354).

> I am having same problem on iPhone 4s. It connects to router then tries to bring me to apple.com page. Then kicks me off network.

Comment: Are you connecting to wifi networks that use a captive portal? (ie, you need to enter a username and password into a browser window before internet will work).

Comment: @ChrisHerbert No - they have WPA2, that's it. I'm using these access points from other devices just fine.

Comment: This was a transient problem where the probe page on Apple .com disappeared. Should probably close this

Answer (score 3):

See this thread at apple.com.
  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4311913?tstart=0

Select the triangle at the right of wi-fi router you're trying to connect to. Scroll to the bottom and change the HTTP Proxy from OFF to AUTO.

Comment: This fixed it for me. After connecting, I was able to switch it back to "off" and can still connect fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with iOS 6 and I just figured it out. You have to reset your all of your network settings. This means you will have to locate and type in the passwords to all of your favorite networks. Nonetheless it has worked so far.

Go to: Settings - General - Reset (at the bottom) - then click "Reset Network Settings".

Then connect to your network, type in the password, and then you should be back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the way I got it working was to forget the network, access the network again (enter password), then, in the network details, tap the slider for Auto-Join or that network.

(As I check the settings now, that slider is not there.  Maybe because I'm currently on the network.)